# DrawerLayout doesn't open

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, navigation

I followed a few tutorials but for some reason (without giving me any errors) the drawer doesn't open. Am I missing something?

My main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 

  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/amber_50"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <include
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      layout="@layout/_toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

 <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/content_frame"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />     

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
  android:id="@+id/nav_view"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="200dp"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

  app:menu="@menu/left_menu" />
```

And in my MainActivity:

```
        toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_logo);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
```

[...]

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.Home:
                drawerLayout.OpenDrawer(Android.Support.V4.View.GravityCompat.Start);
                return true;
        }
    }
```

I've tried changing things around in main.xml, i.e. not implementing fitsSystemWindows, using Relative- instead of FrameLayout, ... . It's not a problem with the Home button since the drawer doesn't open with any other (otherwise functional) button.

Comment: You have to add android:orientation="vertical" in the top LinearLayout.

Comment: YES! Thank you, you're absolutely right. Can you explain why that is?

Comment: Bydefault LinearLayout add children horizontally, and here you need to add children vertically, so you have to add that line.

Comment: remove your `LinearLayout` and make the `DrawerLayout` as your root layout